# JavaScript Array not remove properly in splice

Tags: javascript

I am doing a list of input it's working but when I delete the item and submit again it does changes index and add the new items in the wrong position. Here is a live example https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-curie-bb6yn?file=/src/index.js . Let me know if you need any changes and also if I remove images code and test plain text form it still showing same error.

```js
const Data = [
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/sweets-1.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/sweets-2.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/sweets-3.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/doughnut-1.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/doughnut-2.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/doughnut-3.jpeg",
];

const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submitBtn");
let showLists = document.querySelector(".showLists");

let arry = [];
let count = 0;

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const name = document.querySelector(".name").value;
  const course = document.querySelector(".course").value;
  const author = document.querySelector(".author").value;
  count++;
  if (count === 6) {
    count = 0;
  }

  let x = `
        <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
              <img
                src=${Data[count]}
                class="img-fluid"
              />

                <h4>Name : ${name} </h4>
                <h4>Course : ${course}</h4>
                <h4>Author : ${author}</h4>


              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary deleteBtn">
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>

        `;
  arry.push(x);

  showLists.innerHTML = arry.join(" ");
  deleteBtn();
});

const deleteBtn = () => {
  const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteBtn");
  deleteBtn.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      arry.splice(index, 1);
      e.target.parentElement.remove();
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3">
      <input type="text" id="myInput" class="form-control name" placeholder="Name" title="Type in a name" />
      <input type="text" id="myInput" class="form-control my-3 course" placeholder="Course" title="Type in a name" />
      <input type="text" id="myInput" class="form-control author" placeholder="Author" title="Type in a name" />
      <div class="my-3">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary submitBtn">SUBMIT</button>
      </div>
      <div class="showLists row"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The first argument to `splice()` is an array index, you're passing an HTML string. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Another problem: Every time you add an item you call `deleteBtn()`, which adds additional event listeners to all the delete buttons.

Comment: Can you edit some code in sandbox please

Comment: I don't know what's the purpose of `arry`. Can you explain whether it is really needed variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `arry` variable because I don't see point of keeping this variable. With `innerHtml` you redefine whole content of container `.showLists`, so you must apply listeners again to all buttons. This is not optimal solution. You should consider replacing it for example `appendChild`.

```
const Data = [
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/sweets-1.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/sweets-2.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/sweets-3.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/doughnut-1.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/doughnut-2.jpeg",
  "https://romeojeremiah.github.io/Filter-Project/img/doughnut-3.jpeg"
];

const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submitBtn");
let showLists = document.querySelector(".showLists");
let count = 0;

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const name = document.querySelector(".name").value;
  const course = document.querySelector(".course").value;
  const author = document.querySelector(".author").value;
  count++;
  if (count === 6) {
    count = 0;
  }

  let x = `
  <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
        <img
          src=${Data[count]}
          class="img-fluid"
        />

          <h4>Name : ${name} </h4>
          <h4>Course : ${course}</h4>
          <h4>Author : ${author}</h4>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary deleteBtn">
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>

  `;

  showLists.innerHTML += x;
  deleteBtn();
});

let deleteBtn = () => {
  let deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteBtn");
  console.log(deleteBtn);
  console.log(deleteBtn.length-1);
  deleteBtn.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.target.parentElement.remove();
    });
  });
};
```